Typescript compilation errors when building Angular with SSR + pnpm + preserveSymlinks
I had an Angular app that was building fine. Only quirks of this app is that has preserveSymlinks: true in angular.json and a local library installed for development using the link: protocol in package.json dependencies.
Everything was working until I added SSR following guide in docs by executing
ng add @angular/ssr

Then, ng build failed with several Typescript errors. Here's an excerpt of those (including one of each kind):
✘ [ERROR] TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express-serve-static-core'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:8:22:
      8 │ /// <reference types="express-serve-static-core" />
        ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// ...
✘ [ERROR] TS2307: Cannot find module 'body-parser' or its corresponding type declarations. [plugin angular-compiler]

    node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:11:28:
      11 │ import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
         ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// ... 
✘ [ERROR] TS7006: Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type. [plugin angular-compiler]

    server.ts:28:19:
      28 │   server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
         ╵                    ~~~
// ...
✘ [ERROR] TS2339: Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Express'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    server.ts:51:9:
      51 │   server.listen(port, () => {
         ╵          ~~~~~~
// ...
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "debug"

    node_modules/express/lib/view.js:15:20:
      15 │ var debug = require('debug')('express:view');
         ╵                     ~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "debug" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

Software used:

Angular/Angular CLI/Angular SSR: 17.3.2 (latest when writing this)
Package manager: pnpm 8.15.6 (latest when writing this)
Typescript: 5.4.3 (latest compatible with Angular when writing this)


TL;DR
If using pnpm + preserveSymlinks in Angular CLI's build target options + SSR for an Angular application, set node-linker to hoisted by adding to an .npmrc file in the repo (create it if doesn't exist):
node-linker=hoisted

Then, remove node_modules directory and run pnpm install again. ng build works 

You can also use npm instead of pnpm to solve the issue, but you'll loose the p of pnpm 

Trying to reproduce the issue
After trying to create a minimal reproducible example app, found out that creating a new Angular app with SSR, pnpm as package manager was building properly:
pnpm dlx @angular/cli@17 new a17-ssr --ssr --package-manager=pnpm
pnpm run build

So decided to look for differences between both projects.
Eventually found out I had something different in angular.json. Inside build target options (projects.{name}.architect.build.options): preserveSymlinks was set to true
If disabling it, the app builds properly.
However, I need that option in order to link a local NPM dependency/package. This way I can update the dependency locally and immediately see change in the app without having to reinstall the local dependency.
Tried using npm instead of pnpm to see if that was a package manager issue. Removed node_modules, used npm install and the app built. Even with preserveSymlinks enabled  So seems something related to pnpm installs
The issue
After a quick search, found out it is actually related to how pnpm installs packages. Given dependencies are actually symlinked from node_modules into a pnpm's virtual store at node_modules/.pnpm. And that messes up the build. Unsure why exactly TBH.
The solution
To fix it, we can change the way packages are installed by setting node-linker configuration. See above in TL;DR for how to do it.
Other alternatives
File protocol
Switching to use file: protocol solved the issue. Also preserveSymlinks was no longer required in angular.json workspace configuration. This protocol uses hard-links, so changes to the linked library installed reflect immediately in the app without having to install again. As stated in pnpm docs it works better with peerDependencies resolution.
pnp node-linker
Tried quickly the pnp node-linker strategy with symlink enabled, but build fails due to not found dependencies. Maybe if you properly configure Plug'n'Play it works, but didn't want to spend time on it

Eventually I turned out to use file: protocol to use hard-links instead. This workaround didn't work when testing it for an Angular app in v15 when linked library was built with v17
